# Custom policy: how to get the value of domain_hint as Precondition in an OrchestrationStep?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I'm using custom policies with a CombinedSignInAndSignUp for social accounts and LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange.

Using the `domain_hint` I can skip the selection for social accounts and go directly to e.g. google sign in.

I also want to set `domain_hint` to "LocalAccount" and then ONLY show the local account sign in.

I guess I can do that by adding a first step in the UserJourney to check if `domain_hint`="LocalAccount" and if the ClaimEquals skip the social providers.

I can get the value as output claim when I specify:

```xml
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="domain_hint" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{OIDC:DomainHint}"/>
```

But how do I get the value as Precondition in an OrchestrationStep???

Answer (score 1):

You can use the {OIDC:DomainHint} [claims resolver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview).

Comment: I know. I updated the question: how do I get the value as Precondition in an OrchestrationStep?